# converting dt0 file to tiff in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

I have too many dt0 files containing shear wave velocity at 30 (vs30). I have added the files as raster at QGIS. but I need to convert it to tiff in order to work easier. how can I do so?

Answer (score -1):

Rightclick the layer and choose "save as...".

Comment: as I said there are too many layers. I can convert them individually, but I can't merge them into one tiff.
this is the error: "
Format driver ... does not support creation and piecewise writing.
Please select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine)."